# MySQL - Improve UPDATE Query Performance For Complex Calculations

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to minimise the calculation / query time for the following UPDATE statement that is embedded in a stored procedure on my server...

```
SET @EQUIPMENT_VARIABLE = 'B1010-V001';
UPDATE EQUIPMENT e 
        /*24. MAX COF*/
    SET e.MAX_COF = least(COF_SAFETY, COF_HEALTH, COF_ENVIRONMENT, COF_ASSETS) 
        /*25. RECOMMENDED RBI INTERNAL INTERVAL*/
        , e.RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INTERVAL = (SELECT RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL FROM DAMAGE_MECHANISM WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID = e.EQUIPMENT_ID ORDER BY RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL ASC LIMIT 1)
        /*26. LAST INSPECTION DATE INTERNAL*/
        , e.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL =     (
                                                SELECT a.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE 
                                                FROM CML a LEFT JOIN CML_TYPES b ON a.CML_TYPE = b.CML_TYPE
                                                WHERE a.EQUIPMENT_ID = e.EQUIPMENT_ID AND a.STATUS NOT IN('X') AND b.INTERNAL_EXTERNAL = 'INTERNAL'
                                                ORDER BY LAST_INSPECTION_DATE DESC LIMIT 1
                                                )
        /*27. NEXT INSPECTION DATE INTERNAL*/
        , e.NEXT_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL = DATE_ADD(e.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL, INTERVAL FLOOR(RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INTERVAL * 365) DAY)
        /*28. RECOMMENDED RBI EXTERNAL INTERVAL*/
        , e.RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INTERVAL = (SELECT RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL FROM DAMAGE_MECHANISM WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID = e.EQUIPMENT_ID ORDER BY RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL ASC LIMIT 1)
        /*29. LAST INSPECTION DATE EXERNAL*/
        , e.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL =     (
                                                SELECT a.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE 
                                                FROM CML a LEFT JOIN CML_TYPES b ON a.CML_TYPE = b.CML_TYPE
                                                WHERE a.EQUIPMENT_ID = e.EQUIPMENT_ID AND a.STATUS NOT IN('X') AND b.INTERNAL_EXTERNAL = 'EXTERNAL'
                                                ORDER BY LAST_INSPECTION_DATE DESC LIMIT 1
                                                )
        /*30. NEXT INSPECTION DATE EXTERNAL*/
        , e.NEXT_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL = DATE_ADD(e.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL, INTERVAL FLOOR(RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INTERVAL * 365) DAY)      
        /*31. END OF LIFE*/
        , e.END_OF_LIFE =   (
                            SELECT END_OF_LIFE
                            FROM CML
                            WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID = e.EQUIPMENT_ID AND STATUS NOT IN('X')
                            ORDER BY END_OF_LIFE ASC LIMIT 1
                            )
        /*XX. REMEDIATION STATUS*/
        , e.REMEDIATION_STATUS = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(REMEDIATION_STATUS)) FROM CML WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID = e.EQUIPMENT_ID AND STATUS NOT IN('X'))
        , e.REMEDIATION_STATUS = 
            CASE    WHEN e.REMEDIATION_STATUS IS NOT NULL
                    THEN e.REMEDIATION_STATUS
                    ELSE 'F'
            END
        /*XX. MAX ACR*/
        , e.MAX_ACR = (SELECT APPLIED_CORROSION_RATE FROM CML WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID = e.EQUIPMENT_ID AND STATUS NOT IN ('X') ORDER BY APPLIED_CORROSION_RATE DESC LIMIT 1)
        /*XX. MIN REMAINING LIFE*/
        , e.MIN_REMAINING_LIFE = (SELECT REMAINING_LIFE_BASED_ON_ACR FROM CML WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID = e.EQUIPMENT_ID AND STATUS NOT IN ('X') ORDER BY REMAINING_LIFE_BASED_ON_ACR ASC LIMIT 1)
    WHERE e.EQUIPMENT_ID like @EQUIPMENT_VARIABLE;
```

Any ideas on how I can improve the query structure to minimise the query time / maximise the UPDATE query performance?

** UPDATE **

Approximate number of records in each major table is as follows:

- CML_TYPES: 10
- REMEDIATION_STATUSES: 10
- INSPECTION: 218,000
- CML: 2180
- DAMAGE_MECHANISM: 2180
- EQUIPMENT: 218

Table database structure is provided below.

```
/*CREATE TABLES AND SET DATATYPES*/
/*LOOKUP TABLES TO BE ADDED FIRST SO FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS CAN BE ASSIGNED CORRECTLY*/
CREATE TABLE IDMAS_VESSELS.CML_TYPES
(   /*FIELD NAME*/                                  /*DATA TYPE AND RESTRICTIONS*/
    `CML_TYPE`                                      VARCHAR(50),
    `INTERNAL_EXTERNAL`                             enum('INTERNAL', 'EXTERNAL') default NULL,

    /*PRIMARY AND FOREIGN KEY DEFINITIONS*/
    PRIMARY KEY (CML_TYPE),

    /*ADD TABLE INDEXES TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE*/
    INDEX CML_TYPES_INDEX (CML_TYPE)

) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IDMAS_VESSELS.REMEDIATION_STATUSES
(   /*FIELD NAME*/                                  /*DATA TYPE AND RESTRICTIONS*/
    `REMEDIATION_STATUS`                            VARCHAR(1),
    `DESCRIPTION`                                   VARCHAR(100),

    /*PRIMARY AND FOREIGN KEY DEFINITIONS*/
    PRIMARY KEY (REMEDIATION_STATUS)

    /*ADD TABLE INDEXES TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE*/
    -- PRIMARY KEY INDEXED BY DEFAULT. NO OTHER INDEXES REQUIRED.

) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IDMAS_VESSELS.EQUIPMENT
(   /*FIELD NAME*/                                  /*DATA TYPE AND RESTRICTIONS*/
    `EQUIPMENT_ID`                                  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `EQUIP_TYPE`                                    VARCHAR(50),
    `STATUS_OF_VESSEL`                              enum('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE') NOT NULL default 'ACTIVE',
    `REMEDIATION_STATUS`                            VARCHAR(10),
    `MIN_REMAINING_LIFE`                            DOUBLE,
    `MAX_ACR`                                       DOUBLE,
    `END_OF_LIFE`                                   DATE,
    `AREA`                                          VARCHAR(50),
    `EQUIP_FROM`                                    VARCHAR(50),
    `EQUIP_TO`                                      VARCHAR(20),
    `CONTENTS`                                      VARCHAR(50),
    `COMMENTS`                                      TEXT,
    `MATERIAL`                                      VARCHAR(50),
    `MATERIAL_SPECIFICATION`                        VARCHAR(2),
    `CORROSION_ALLOWANCE (MM)`                      DOUBLE(2,2),
    `CONSTRUCTION_CODE`                             VARCHAR(20),
    `DESIGN_PRESSURE_MPA`                           DOUBLE,
    `DESIGN_TEMPERATURE_DEGC`                       DOUBLE,
    `PID`                                           VARCHAR(20),
    `DRAWING_REF`                                   VARCHAR(20),
    `OPERATING_PRESSURE_KPA`                        DOUBLE,
    `OPERATING_TEMP_DEGC`                           DOUBLE,
    `CAPACITY_L`                                    DOUBLE,
    `CAPACITY_MPA_PER_L`                            DOUBLE,
    `MAXIMUM_ALLOWABLE_WORKING_PRESSURE_MPA`        DOUBLE,
    `MAXIMUM_ALLOWABLE_WORKING_TEMPERATURE_DEGC`    DOUBLE,
    `DESIGN_STRENGTH_MPA`                           DOUBLE,
    `JOINT_EFFICIENCY`                              DOUBLE,
    `COF_SAFETY`                                    INT(1),
    `COF_HEALTH`                                    INT(1),
    `COF_ENVIRONMENT`                               INT(1),
    `COF_ASSETS`                                    INT(1),
    `MAX_COF`                                       INT(1),
    `HAZARD_LEVEL`                                  CHAR(1),
    `CONTENTS_CLASS`                                VARCHAR(50),
    `INSTALLATION_YEAR`                             DATE,
    `INTERIOR_COATING`                              VARCHAR(50),
    `EXTERIOR_COATING`                              VARCHAR(50),
    `EXTERIOR_INSUL`                                VARCHAR(50),
    `MANUFACTURER`                                  VARCHAR(50),
    `MANUFACTURE_DATE`                              DATE,
    `MANUFACTURE_NO`                                VARCHAR(50),
    `INTERNAL_ANODES`                               VARCHAR(50),
    `ASSOC_PSV`                                     VARCHAR(50),
    `MAINT_ITEM_CODE`                               VARCHAR(50),
    `SERV_TYPE`                                     VARCHAR(50),
    `EQUIP_CLASS`                                   VARCHAR(50),
    `EQUIP_SUBCLASS`                                VARCHAR(50),
    `PROCESS_UNIT`                                  VARCHAR(50),
    `RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INTERVAL`             DOUBLE,
    `LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL`                 DATE,
    `NEXT_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL`                 DATE,
    `RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INTERVAL`             DOUBLE,
    `LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL`                 DATE,
    `NEXT_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL`                 DATE,
    `DESIGN_LIFE`                                   DOUBLE,

    /*PRIMARY AND FOREIGN KEY DEFINITIONS*/
    PRIMARY KEY (EQUIPMENT_ID),

    /*INDEX FIELDS TO INCREASE PERFORMANCE REDUCES NUMBER OF ACCESSES (N) FROM N to LOG2(N) I.E. AN EXPONENTIAL DECREASE
     *APPLYING THESE INDEXES TO PRIMARY KEY FIELDS ALSO REMOVES THE REQUIREMENT FOR THE SYSTEM TO SEARCH FOR DUPLICATES
     *INDEXES ONLY INCREASE THE DISK SPACE REQUIRED OF THE DATABASE.
     *ALL DATABASE SEARCHING SHOULD ALWAYS BE DONE ON THE PRIMARY KEY INDEXED FIELD.
     */
    INDEX EQUIPMENT_INDEX (EQUIPMENT_ID)

) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IDMAS_VESSELS.DAMAGE_MECHANISM
(   /*FIELD NAME*/                                              /*DATA TYPE AND RESTRICTIONS*/
    `DAMAGE_MECHANISM_ID`                                       VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `EQUIPMENT_ID`                                              VARCHAR(20),
    `DESCRIPTION`                                               VARCHAR(50),
    `REMEDIATION_STATUS`                                        VARCHAR(10),
    `DAMAGE_MECHANISM_TYPE`                                     enum('QUALITATIVE', 'QUANTITATIVE') default NULL,
    `INSPECTION_STRATEGY`                                       VARCHAR(20),
    `AGE_RELATED`                                               enum('YES', 'NO') NOT NULL default 'NO',
    `FEASIBLE`                                                  enum('YES', 'NO') NOT NULL default 'NO',
    `NOTES_ON_FEASIBILITY`                                      TEXT,
    `MIN_REMAINING_LIFE`                                        DOUBLE,
    `MAX_ACR`                                                   DOUBLE,
    `MINIMUM_CALCULATED_RBI_INTERVAL`                           DOUBLE,
    `MAXIMUM_CRITICALITY_RATING`                                VARCHAR(20),
    `RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL`              DOUBLE,
    `LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL`                             DATE,
    `NEXT_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL`                             DATE,
    `NOTES_ON_RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL`     TEXT,
    `RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL`              DOUBLE,
    `LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL`                             DATE,
    `NEXT_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL`                             DATE,
    `NOTES_ON_RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL`     TEXT,

    /*PRIMARY AND FOREIGN KEY DEFINITIONS*/
    PRIMARY KEY (DAMAGE_MECHANISM_ID, EQUIPMENT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (EQUIPMENT_ID) REFERENCES EQUIPMENT(EQUIPMENT_ID),

    /*ADD TABLE INDEXES TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE*/
    INDEX DAMAGE_MECHANISM_INDEX (EQUIPMENT_ID, DAMAGE_MECHANISM_ID)

) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IDMAS_VESSELS.CML
(   /*FIELD NAME*/                                  /*DATA TYPE AND RESTRICTIONS*/
    `CML_ID`                                        INT NOT NULL,
    `CML_LOCATION`                                  VARCHAR(20),
    `STATUS`                                        enum('C','X','A','U') NOT NULL default 'C',
    `REMEDIATION_STATUS`                            VARCHAR(1),
    `EQUIPMENT_ID`                                  VARCHAR(20),
    `DAMAGE_MECHANISM_ID`                           VARCHAR(50),
    `CML_TYPE`                                      VARCHAR(50),
    `LAST_INSPECTION_DATE`                          DATE,
    `NOMINAL_DIAMETER_MM`                           DOUBLE,
    `OUTSIDE_DIAMETER_MM`                           DOUBLE,
    `MEAN_DIAMETER_MM`                              DOUBLE,
    `NOMINAL_WALL_THICKNESS_MM`                     DOUBLE,
    `MINIMUM_REMAINING_WALL_THICKNESS_MM`           DOUBLE,
    `DEPTH_OF_LOSS_FROM_NWT_MM`                     DOUBLE,
    `THICKNESS_WALL_LOSS_PERCENTAGE`                DOUBLE,
    `PHOTO`                                         INT,
    `MINIMUM_ALLOWABLE_WALL_THICKNESS_MM`           DOUBLE,
    `ACTUAL_CORROSION_RATE_MM_PER_YEAR`             DOUBLE,
    `MAX_CALCULATED_CORROSION_RATE`                 DOUBLE,
    `DAMAGE_LOOP_MAXIMUM_CORROSION_RATE`            DOUBLE,
    `APPLIED_CORROSION_RATE`                        DOUBLE,
    `APPLIED_CORROSION_RATE_NOTES_AND_ENTERED_BY`   TEXT,
    `FAILURE_MODE`                                  VARCHAR(50),
    `REMAINING_LIFE_BASED_ON_ACR`                   DOUBLE,
    `END_OF_LIFE`                                   DATE,
    `LR_LD_APPLIED`                                 DOUBLE,
    `POF_APPLIED`                                   INT(1),
    `DAMAGE_MECHANISM_VISUAL`                       TEXT,
    `FAILURE_MODE_VISUAL`                           TEXT,
    `POF_APPLIED_VISUAL`                            INT(1),
    `POF_APPLIED_VISUAL_COMMENT`                    TEXT,
    `CRITICALITY_RATING_VISUAL`                     INT(2),
    `CRITICALITY_RATING_APPLIED`                    VARCHAR(10),
    `DEGRADATION_MECHANISM`                         DOUBLE,
    `RELIABLE_MONITORING`                           DOUBLE,
    `MULTIPLE_INSPECTIONS`                          DOUBLE,
    `CONFIDENCE_SCORE`                              DOUBLE,
    `CONFIDENCE_RATING`                             VARCHAR(50),
    `INSPECTION_INTERVAL_FACTOR_APPLIED`            DOUBLE,
    `RISK_BASED_INSPECTION_INTERVAL_APPLIED_YEARS`  DOUBLE,
    `RECOMMENDED_REMEDIATION`                       TEXT,

    /*PRIMARY AND FOREIGN KEY DEFINITIONS*/
    PRIMARY KEY (EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (EQUIPMENT_ID, DAMAGE_MECHANISM_ID) REFERENCES DAMAGE_MECHANISM(EQUIPMENT_ID, DAMAGE_MECHANISM_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CML_TYPE) REFERENCES CML_TYPES(CML_TYPE),
    FOREIGN KEY (REMEDIATION_STATUS) REFERENCES REMEDIATION_STATUSES(REMEDIATION_STATUS),

    /*ADD TABLE INDEXES TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE*/
    INDEX CML_INDEX (EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID)

) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IDMAS_VESSELS.INSPECTION
(   /*FIELD NAME*/                                  /*DATA TYPE AND RESTRICTIONS*/
    `INSPECTION_NO`                                 INT NOT NULL,
    `STATUS`                                        enum('P','A','S','R') NOT NULL default 'P',
    `CML_ID`                                        INT NOT NULL,
    `EQUIPMENT_ID`                                  VARCHAR(20),
    `INSPECTION_TYPE`                               VARCHAR(50),
    `SCOPE_COMMENTS`                                TEXT,
    `NOMINAL_WALL_THICKNESS`                        DOUBLE,
    `MINIMUM_REMAINING_WALL_THICKNESS`              DOUBLE,
    `WALL_LOSS`                                     DOUBLE,
    `SERVICE_YEARS`                                 DOUBLE,
    `CORROSION_RATE_ACTUAL_SHORT_TERM_MM_PER_YEAR`  DOUBLE,
    `CONDITION`                                     VARCHAR(50),
    `INSPECTION_DATE`                               DATE,
    `NDT_REPORT_NUMBER`                             VARCHAR(20),
    `INSPECTION_COMMENTS`                           TEXT,
    `INSPECTION_SCOPE`                              TEXT,
    `WORK_ORDER`                                    TEXT,
    `INPECTOR_NAME`                                 VARCHAR(50),
    `INPECTION_COMPANY`                             VARCHAR(50),
    `PHOTO`                                         INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    /*PRIMARY AND FOREIGN KEY DEFINITIONS*/
    PRIMARY KEY (EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID, INSPECTION_NO),
    FOREIGN KEY (EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID) REFERENCES CML(EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID),

    /*ADD TABLE INDEXES TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE*/
    /*INDEX ON PHOTO FIELD REQUIRED TO ALLOW AUTO INCREMENTING OF FIELD*/
    INDEX INSPECTION_INDEX (EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID, INSPECTION_NO),
    INDEX `PHOTO` (`PHOTO`)
    -- INDEX INSPECTION_DATE (INSPECTION_DATE)

) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Two observations: 1. There's quite a lot of query there. 2. I'm a little surprised that a 'maximum' of anything would be defined as a floating point number.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Do you have any ideas on how to address the two points you have raised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## suggested solution for update of all equipments

```
UPDATE      EQUIPMENT e 

            left join  (SELECT      EQUIPMENT_ID
                                   ,min(RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL)  as MIN_RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL /*25. RECOMMENDED RBI INTERNAL INTERVAL*/
                                   ,min(RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL)  as MIN_RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL /*28. RECOMMENDED RBI EXTERNAL INTERVAL*/

                        FROM        DAMAGE_MECHANISM 

                        group by     EQUIPMENT_ID
                        ) dm
                        
            on          dm.EQUIPMENT_ID = e.EQUIPMENT_ID
              
            left join  (SELECT      EQUIPMENT_ID
                                   ,max(case b.INTERNAL_EXTERNAL when 'INTERNAL' then a.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE end) MIN_LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL    /*26. LAST INSPECTION DATE INTERNAL*/
                                   ,max(case b.INTERNAL_EXTERNAL when 'EXTERNAL' then a.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE end) MIN_LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL    /*29. LAST INSPECTION DATE EXERNAL*/
                                   ,min(END_OF_LIFE)                            as min_END_OF_LIFE                          /*31. END OF LIFE*/
                                   ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT REMEDIATION_STATUS)   as GROUP_CONCAT_DISTINCT_REMEDIATION_STATUS /*XX. REMEDIATION STATUS*/
                                   ,max(APPLIED_CORROSION_RATE)                 as max_APPLIED_CORROSION_RATE
                                   ,min(REMAINING_LIFE_BASED_ON_ACR)            as min_REMAINING_LIFE_BASED_ON_ACR
                                   
                        FROM        CML a JOIN CML_TYPES b ON a.CML_TYPE = b.CML_TYPE

                        WHERE       a.STATUS NOT IN('X')
                        
                        group by    EQUIPMENT_ID
                        ) ct
                        
            on          ct.EQUIPMENT_ID = e.EQUIPMENT_ID                        
            
SET         e.MAX_COF                           = least(COF_SAFETY, COF_HEALTH, COF_ENVIRONMENT, COF_ASSETS)                                            /*24. MAX COF*/            
           ,e.RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INTERVAL = dm.MIN_RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL                                                   /*25. RECOMMENDED RBI INTERNAL INTERVAL*/        
           ,e.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL     = ct.MIN_LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL                                                                  /*26. LAST INSPECTION DATE INTERNAL*/
           ,e.NEXT_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL     = DATE_ADD(e.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL,INTERVAL FLOOR(RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INTERVAL*365) DAY)   /*27. NEXT INSPECTION DATE INTERNAL*/
           ,e.RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INTERVAL = dm.MIN_RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL                                                   /*28. RECOMMENDED RBI EXTERNAL INTERVAL*/
           ,e.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL     = ct.MIN_LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL                                                                  /*29. LAST INSPECTION DATE EXERNAL*/
           ,e.NEXT_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL     = DATE_ADD(e.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL,INTERVAL FLOOR(RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INTERVAL*365) DAY)   /*30. NEXT INSPECTION DATE EXTERNAL*/  
           ,e.END_OF_LIFE                       = ct.min_END_OF_LIFE                                                                                    /*31. END OF LIFE*/
           ,e.REMEDIATION_STATUS                = coalesce(ct.GROUP_CONCAT_DISTINCT_REMEDIATION_STATUS,'F')                                             /*XX. REMEDIATION STATUS*/
           ,e.MAX_ACR                           = ct.max_APPLIED_CORROSION_RATE                                                                         /*XX. MAX ACR*/
           ,e.MIN_REMAINING_LIFE                = ct.min_REMAINING_LIFE_BASED_ON_ACR                                                                    /*XX. MIN REMAINING LIFE*/
;
```

Comment: Tested this version and it takes about 0.031 seconds on average to do the entire database. Out of interest, why have you used GROUP BY statements in the nested queries?

Comment: @Josh, the previous version was designed to update a single equipment. In order to use it to update the whole equipment table you have to loop on the equipment's' list and call the procedure again and again which as it cost. Also, you'll have to read parts of the tables for each equipment. It is faster to call a single procedure and retrieve whole the needed information only once.

Comment: Ah, I see... minimizing the double dipping on tables. Good stuff Dudu. I'll mark both of these solutions as answers. You've been a great help.

Comment: i've updated the question with another embedded UPDATE statement that I have tried applying the learnings from this answer. Can you potentially have a look and see if you can optimise it further? :)

Comment: Oh sorry Dudu didnt realize it did that!! Ill re-accept and open a new question then! :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace all the `order by ... limit 1` functionality with min/max.
min/max complexity in O(n) while sort complexity is O(n*log n).
You'll notice a difference for large data sets.

---

The `LEFT JOINs` are actually `INNER JOINs` because of conditions on the right table such as `b.INTERNAL_EXTERNAL = 'INTERNAL'`

---

`INDEX CML_TYPES_INDEX (CML_TYPE)` is duplication of `PRIMARY KEY (CML_TYPE)`

`INDEX CML_INDEX (EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID)` is duplication of `PRIMARY KEY (EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID)`

etc.

It seems to be way too much indexes in the system.
For every couple of columns there is an index for (A) and for (B) and for (A,B) and for (B,A).

1. This usually drives the optimizer to generate bad execution plans.
2. You pay a lot for every DML operation (insert/update/delete)

---

The indexes on the small tables might damage the performance
Full table scan might require less reads than traversing the index blocks.

---

In the following code -
`WHERE e.EQUIPMENT_ID like @EQUIPMENT_VARIABLE`

Do you use only fixed string (no '%' and '_') like in 
`SET @EQUIPMENT_VARIABLE = 'B1010-V001'`

so the `like` can be actually replaced with `=`?

Comment: No worries I can get this information for you, but what specific DLL are you after from MySQL?

Comment: Also why does the min/max function perform better than the limit 1 approach?

Comment: tables' definition including indexes

Comment: This is probably a dumb question but where do I locate that file?

Comment: I believe the acronym DLL means something different to us both. What does it stand for in this context?

Comment: Data Definition Language

Comment: Ok updated the question with the DDL. as for current and expected execution time I am really just after ge\neral suggestions to maximise the performance where i can. As I have many SQL UPDATE statements in a similar format to that provided in the question and am planning on applying these general rules to all of them.

Comment: There are multiple tables in your code. Also please add some data characteristic, e.g. number of rows in each table

Comment: Great. I have to quit for now. If no one will answer in the meantime, I'll get back to it later.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments. I can replace likes with ='s. The likes were included only so I could recalculate the entire system using the % operator. But I can handle this procedure in a different way if it yields better performance increases to use =. Also you mentioned to use INNER JOINS rather than LEFT JOINS can you elaborate why it is faster to design the query like this? And I didnt really understand why I should eliminate indexes from small tables? can you again elaborate? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## Suggested code

1. I assumed the `like` can be replace with `=`.
2. The main key here is to retrieve only once from each source table.

---

```
SET @EQUIPMENT_VARIABLE = 'B1010-V001'
;


UPDATE      EQUIPMENT e 

            left join  (SELECT      min(RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL)  as MIN_RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL /*25. RECOMMENDED RBI INTERNAL INTERVAL*/
                                   ,min(RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL)  as MIN_RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL /*28. RECOMMENDED RBI EXTERNAL INTERVAL*/

                        FROM        DAMAGE_MECHANISM 

                        WHERE       EQUIPMENT_ID = @EQUIPMENT_VARIABLE
                        ) dm

            on  true

            left join  (SELECT      max(case b.INTERNAL_EXTERNAL when 'INTERNAL' then a.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE end) MIN_LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL    /*26. LAST INSPECTION DATE INTERNAL*/
                                   ,max(case b.INTERNAL_EXTERNAL when 'EXTERNAL' then a.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE end) MIN_LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL    /*29. LAST INSPECTION DATE EXERNAL*/
                                   ,min(END_OF_LIFE)                            as min_END_OF_LIFE                          /*31. END OF LIFE*/
                                   ,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT REMEDIATION_STATUS)   as GROUP_CONCAT_DISTINCT_REMEDIATION_STATUS /*XX. REMEDIATION STATUS*/
                                   ,max(APPLIED_CORROSION_RATE)                 as max_APPLIED_CORROSION_RATE
                                   ,min(REMAINING_LIFE_BASED_ON_ACR)            as min_REMAINING_LIFE_BASED_ON_ACR

                        FROM        CML a JOIN CML_TYPES b ON a.CML_TYPE = b.CML_TYPE

                        WHERE       a.EQUIPMENT_ID = @EQUIPMENT_VARIABLE AND a.STATUS NOT IN('X')
                        ) ct
                        
            on  true

SET         e.MAX_COF                           = least(COF_SAFETY, COF_HEALTH, COF_ENVIRONMENT, COF_ASSETS)                                            /*24. MAX COF*/            
           ,e.RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INTERVAL = dm.MIN_RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL                                                   /*25. RECOMMENDED RBI INTERNAL INTERVAL*/        
           ,e.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL     = ct.MIN_LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL                                                                  /*26. LAST INSPECTION DATE INTERNAL*/
           ,e.NEXT_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL     = DATE_ADD(e.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL,INTERVAL FLOOR(RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INTERVAL*365) DAY)   /*27. NEXT INSPECTION DATE INTERNAL*/
           ,e.RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INTERVAL = dm.MIN_RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL                                                   /*28. RECOMMENDED RBI EXTERNAL INTERVAL*/
           ,e.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL     = ct.MIN_LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL                                                                  /*29. LAST INSPECTION DATE EXERNAL*/
           ,e.NEXT_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL     = DATE_ADD(e.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL,INTERVAL FLOOR(RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INTERVAL*365) DAY)   /*30. NEXT INSPECTION DATE EXTERNAL*/  
           ,e.END_OF_LIFE                       = ct.min_END_OF_LIFE                                                                                    /*31. END OF LIFE*/
           ,e.REMEDIATION_STATUS                = coalesce(ct.GROUP_CONCAT_DISTINCT_REMEDIATION_STATUS,'F')                                             /*XX. REMEDIATION STATUS*/
           ,e.MAX_ACR                           = ct.max_APPLIED_CORROSION_RATE                                                                         /*XX. MAX ACR*/
           ,e.MIN_REMAINING_LIFE                = ct.min_REMAINING_LIFE_BASED_ON_ACR                                                                    /*XX. MIN REMAINING LIFE*/

WHERE       e.EQUIPMENT_ID = @EQUIPMENT_VARIABLE
;
```

Comment: Thanks dudu. I'll run some tests on the code now and get back to you.

Comment: Damn Dudu, this is fast now. Query time went from 0.016 per equipment to 0.000 seconds. This is a fantastic performance increase. I will be incorporating this into all of my queries now! A few questions though. Why have you used 'Cross Joins' and included the WHERE clauses in the nested queries at each stage?

Comment: @Josh, just did another change (merged 2 sub queries) please recheck

Comment: I like it even cleaner approach. Takes only 0.032 seconds to recalculate ALL equipment in the database.

Comment: For all equipment  I would go with a slightly different approach. I'll add another answer in any minute :-)

Comment: You ma boiiiii! :)

Comment: @Josh, since I don't know the data and I can't be sure that every equipment has a row in every sub-query, I've replaced the `cross join` with `left join ... on true`