# MySQL - Improve UPDATE Query Performance for Complex Calculations Round 2

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

This question is similar to the question answered in the following link, however it involves a different embedded UPDATE query.

[MySQL - Improve UPDATE Query Performance For Complex Calculations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40232320/mysql-improve-update-query-performance-for-complex-calculations/40251864?noredirect=1#comment68084101_40251864)

I am trying to minimize the calculation / query time for the following UPDATE statement that is embedded in a stored procedure on my server...

```
UPDATE CML c 
LEFT JOIN   (
            SELECT EQUIPMENT_ID, INSTALLATION_YEAR, least(COF_SAFETY, COF_HEALTH, COF_ENVIRONMENT, COF_ASSETS) AS VIRTUAL_MAX_COF, DESIGN_LIFE
            FROM EQUIPMENT 
            WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID = @EQUIPMENT_VARIABLE
            ) E
ON E.EQUIPMENT_ID = c.EQUIPMENT_ID
LEFT JOIN   (
            SELECT  EQUIPMENT_ID
                    , CML_ID
                    , GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'S' THEN 'S' END)                                             AS SCOPED_INSPECTIONS
                    , MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS IN('A','R') THEN INSPECTION_DATE END)                                    AS MAX_INSPECTION_DATE
                    , MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS IN('A','R') THEN CORROSION_RATE_ACTUAL_SHORT_TERM_MM_PER_YEAR END)       AS MAX_CORROSION_RATE_ACTUAL_SHORT_TERM_MM_PER_YEAR
            FROM INSPECTION
            WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID = @EQUIPMENT_VARIABLE
            GROUP BY EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID
            ) I
ON I.EQUIPMENT_ID = c.EQUIPMENT_ID AND I.CML_ID = c.CML_ID 
SET c.STATUS                                                    = CASE WHEN c.STATUS NOT IN('X') THEN COALESCE(I.SCOPED_INSPECTIONS, c.STATUS) ELSE c.STATUS END
    , c.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE                                    = COALESCE(I.MAX_INSPECTION_DATE, E.INSTALLATION_YEAR)
    , c.MEAN_DIAMETER_MM                                        = CASE WHEN c.STATUS NOT IN ('X') THEN c.OUTSIDE_DIAMETER_MM - c.NOMINAL_WALL_THICKNESS_MM ELSE NULL END
    , c.MINIMUM_REMAINING_WALL_THICKNESS_MM                     = CASE  WHEN c.STATUS NOT IN ('X')
                                                                        THEN    (   
                                                                                SELECT MIN(MINIMUM_REMAINING_WALL_THICKNESS)
                                                                                FROM INSPECTION 
                                                                                WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID = c.EQUIPMENT_ID AND CML_ID = c.CML_ID AND STATUS IN('A','R') AND INSPECTION_DATE = c.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE
                                                                                )
                                                                        ELSE NULL
                                                                  END
    , c.DEPTH_OF_LOSS_FROM_NWT_MM                               = CASE WHEN c.STATUS NOT IN ('X') THEN c.NOMINAL_WALL_THICKNESS_MM - c.MINIMUM_REMAINING_WALL_THICKNESS_MM ELSE NULL END
    , c.THICKNESS_WALL_LOSS_PERCENTAGE                          = CASE WHEN c.STATUS NOT IN ('X') THEN (c.DEPTH_OF_LOSS_FROM_NWT_MM / c.NOMINAL_WALL_THICKNESS_MM) * 100 ELSE NULL END
    , c.PHOTO                                                   =   (
                                                                    SELECT MAX(PHOTO)
                                                                    FROM INSPECTION 
                                                                    WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID = c.EQUIPMENT_ID AND CML_ID = c.CML_ID AND INSPECTION_DATE = c.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE
                                                                    )
    , c.ACTUAL_CORROSION_RATE_MM_PER_YEAR                       = CASE  WHEN c.STATUS NOT IN ('X')
                                                                        THEN    (
                                                                                SELECT MAX(CORROSION_RATE_ACTUAL_SHORT_TERM_MM_PER_YEAR)
                                                                                FROM INSPECTION 
                                                                                WHERE EQUIPMENT_ID = c.EQUIPMENT_ID AND CML_ID = c.CML_ID AND STATUS IN ('A') AND INSPECTION_DATE = c.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE
                                                                                )
                                                                        ELSE NULL
                                                                  END
    , c.MAX_CALCULATED_CORROSION_RATE                           = CASE WHEN c.STATUS NOT IN ('X') THEN I.MAX_CORROSION_RATE_ACTUAL_SHORT_TERM_MM_PER_YEAR ELSE NULL END
    , c.REMAINING_LIFE_BASED_ON_ACR                             = CASE WHEN c.STATUS NOT IN ('X') THEN (c.MINIMUM_REMAINING_WALL_THICKNESS_MM - c.MINIMUM_ALLOWABLE_WALL_THICKNESS_MM) / c.APPLIED_CORROSION_RATE ELSE NULL END
    , c.END_OF_LIFE                                             = CASE WHEN c.STATUS NOT IN ('X') THEN DATE_ADD(c.LAST_INSPECTION_DATE, INTERVAL FLOOR(REMAINING_LIFE_BASED_ON_ACR * 365) DAY) ELSE NULL END
    , c.LR_LD_APPLIED                                           = CASE WHEN c.STATUS NOT IN ('X') THEN c.REMAINING_LIFE_BASED_ON_ACR / E.DESIGN_LIFE ELSE NULL END
    , c.POF_APPLIED                                             =   CASE    WHEN c.STATUS NOT IN ('X')
                                                                            THEN    CASE    WHEN c.LR_LD_APPLIED < 0.5
                                                                                            THEN 1
                                                                                            WHEN c.LR_LD_APPLIED >= 0.5 AND c.LR_LD_APPLIED < 0.8
                                                                                            THEN 2
                                                                                            WHEN c.LR_LD_APPLIED >= 0.8 AND c.LR_LD_APPLIED < 1.2
                                                                                            THEN 3
                                                                                            WHEN c.LR_LD_APPLIED >= 1.2 AND c.LR_LD_APPLIED < 2
                                                                                            THEN 4
                                                                                            WHEN c.LR_LD_APPLIED >= 2 
                                                                                            THEN 5
                                                                                            ELSE NULL
                                                                                    END
                                                                            ELSE NULL
                                                                    END
    , c.CRITICALITY_RATING_APPLIED                              = CASE  WHEN c.STATUS NOT IN ('X')
                                                                        THEN    CASE    WHEN (E.VIRTUAL_MAX_COF + c.POF_APPLIED - 1) < 5
                                                                                        THEN 'SEVERE'
                                                                                        WHEN (E.VIRTUAL_MAX_COF + c.POF_APPLIED - 1) = 5
                                                                                        THEN 'HIGH'
                                                                                        WHEN (E.VIRTUAL_MAX_COF + c.POF_APPLIED - 1) = 6
                                                                                        THEN 'MEDIUM'
                                                                                        WHEN (E.VIRTUAL_MAX_COF + c.POF_APPLIED - 1) > 6
                                                                                        THEN 'LOW'
                                                                                        ELSE NULL
                                                                                END
                                                                        ELSE NULL
                                                                    END
    , c.CONFIDENCE_SCORE                                        = 
                                                                    CASE    WHEN c.STATUS NOT IN ('X')
                                                                            THEN c.DEGRADATION_MECHANISM + c.RELIABLE_MONITORING + c.MULTIPLE_INSPECTIONS           
                                                                            ELSE NULL
                                                                    END     
    , c.CONFIDENCE_RATING                                       =   CASE    WHEN c.STATUS NOT IN ('X')
                                                                            THEN    CASE    WHEN c.CONFIDENCE_SCORE >= 0.2
                                                                                            THEN 'VERY HIGH'
                                                                                            WHEN c.CONFIDENCE_SCORE = 0.1
                                                                                            THEN 'HIGH'
                                                                                            WHEN c.CONFIDENCE_SCORE = 0
                                                                                            THEN 'MEDIUM'
                                                                                            WHEN c.CONFIDENCE_SCORE = -0.1
                                                                                            THEN 'LOW'
                                                                                            WHEN c.CONFIDENCE_SCORE <= -0.2
                                                                                            THEN 'VERY LOW'
                                                                                            ELSE NULL
                                                                                    END
                                                                            ELSE NULL
                                                                    END
        , c.INSPECTION_INTERVAL_FACTOR_APPLIED                  =   CASE    WHEN c.STATUS NOT IN ('X')
                                                                            THEN    (
                                                                                        (
                                                                                        CASE    WHEN CONFIDENCE_RATING = 'VERY HIGH'
                                                                                                THEN 5
                                                                                                WHEN CONFIDENCE_RATING = 'HIGH'
                                                                                                THEN 4
                                                                                                WHEN CONFIDENCE_RATING = 'MEDIUM'
                                                                                                THEN 3
                                                                                                WHEN CONFIDENCE_RATING = 'LOW'
                                                                                                THEN 2
                                                                                                WHEN CONFIDENCE_RATING = 'VERY LOW'
                                                                                                THEN 1
                                                                                                ELSE NULL
                                                                                        END
                                                                                        ) 
                                                                                        + 
                                                                                        (
                                                                                        CASE    WHEN CRITICALITY_RATING_APPLIED = 'SEVERE'
                                                                                                THEN 1
                                                                                                WHEN CRITICALITY_RATING_APPLIED = 'HIGH'
                                                                                                THEN 2
                                                                                                WHEN CRITICALITY_RATING_APPLIED = 'MEDIUM'
                                                                                                THEN 3
                                                                                                WHEN CRITICALITY_RATING_APPLIED = 'LOW'
                                                                                                THEN 4
                                                                                                ELSE NULL
                                                                                        END
                                                                                        ) 
                                                                                    - 2) / 10
                                                                            ELSE NULL
                                                                    END
            , c.RISK_BASED_INSPECTION_INTERVAL_APPLIED_YEARS    =   CASE    WHEN c.STATUS NOT IN ('X')
                                                                            THEN c.INSPECTION_INTERVAL_FACTOR_APPLIED * c.REMAINING_LIFE_BASED_ON_ACR       
                                                                            ELSE NULL
                                                                    END
WHERE c.EQUIPMENT_ID = @EQUIPMENT_VARIABLE;
```

Any ideas on how I can improve the query structures to minimize the query time / maximize the UPDATE query performance?

Approximate number of records in each major table is as follows:

- CML_TYPES: 10
- REMEDIATION_STATUSES: 10
- INSPECTION: 218,000
- CML: 2180
- DAMAGE_MECHANISM: 2180
- EQUIPMENT: 218

Table database structure is provided below.

```
/*CREATE TABLES AND SET DATATYPES*/
/*LOOKUP TABLES TO BE ADDED FIRST SO FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS CAN BE ASSIGNED CORRECTLY*/
CREATE TABLE IDMAS_VESSELS.CML_TYPES
(   /*FIELD NAME*/                                  /*DATA TYPE AND RESTRICTIONS*/
    `CML_TYPE`                                      VARCHAR(50),
    `INTERNAL_EXTERNAL`                             enum('INTERNAL', 'EXTERNAL') default NULL,

    /*PRIMARY AND FOREIGN KEY DEFINITIONS*/
    PRIMARY KEY (CML_TYPE),

    /*ADD TABLE INDEXES TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE*/
    INDEX CML_TYPES_INDEX (CML_TYPE)

) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IDMAS_VESSELS.REMEDIATION_STATUSES
(   /*FIELD NAME*/                                  /*DATA TYPE AND RESTRICTIONS*/
    `REMEDIATION_STATUS`                            VARCHAR(1),
    `DESCRIPTION`                                   VARCHAR(100),

    /*PRIMARY AND FOREIGN KEY DEFINITIONS*/
    PRIMARY KEY (REMEDIATION_STATUS)

    /*ADD TABLE INDEXES TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE*/
    -- PRIMARY KEY INDEXED BY DEFAULT. NO OTHER INDEXES REQUIRED.

) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IDMAS_VESSELS.EQUIPMENT
(   /*FIELD NAME*/                                  /*DATA TYPE AND RESTRICTIONS*/
    `EQUIPMENT_ID`                                  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `EQUIP_TYPE`                                    VARCHAR(50),
    `STATUS_OF_VESSEL`                              enum('ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE') NOT NULL default 'ACTIVE',
    `REMEDIATION_STATUS`                            VARCHAR(10),
    `MIN_REMAINING_LIFE`                            DOUBLE,
    `MAX_ACR`                                       DOUBLE,
    `END_OF_LIFE`                                   DATE,
    `AREA`                                          VARCHAR(50),
    `EQUIP_FROM`                                    VARCHAR(50),
    `EQUIP_TO`                                      VARCHAR(20),
    `CONTENTS`                                      VARCHAR(50),
    `COMMENTS`                                      TEXT,
    `MATERIAL`                                      VARCHAR(50),
    `MATERIAL_SPECIFICATION`                        VARCHAR(2),
    `CORROSION_ALLOWANCE (MM)`                      DOUBLE(2,2),
    `CONSTRUCTION_CODE`                             VARCHAR(20),
    `DESIGN_PRESSURE_MPA`                           DOUBLE,
    `DESIGN_TEMPERATURE_DEGC`                       DOUBLE,
    `PID`                                           VARCHAR(20),
    `DRAWING_REF`                                   VARCHAR(20),
    `OPERATING_PRESSURE_KPA`                        DOUBLE,
    `OPERATING_TEMP_DEGC`                           DOUBLE,
    `CAPACITY_L`                                    DOUBLE,
    `CAPACITY_MPA_PER_L`                            DOUBLE,
    `MAXIMUM_ALLOWABLE_WORKING_PRESSURE_MPA`        DOUBLE,
    `MAXIMUM_ALLOWABLE_WORKING_TEMPERATURE_DEGC`    DOUBLE,
    `DESIGN_STRENGTH_MPA`                           DOUBLE,
    `JOINT_EFFICIENCY`                              DOUBLE,
    `COF_SAFETY`                                    INT(1),
    `COF_HEALTH`                                    INT(1),
    `COF_ENVIRONMENT`                               INT(1),
    `COF_ASSETS`                                    INT(1),
    `MAX_COF`                                       INT(1),
    `HAZARD_LEVEL`                                  CHAR(1),
    `CONTENTS_CLASS`                                VARCHAR(50),
    `INSTALLATION_YEAR`                             DATE,
    `INTERIOR_COATING`                              VARCHAR(50),
    `EXTERIOR_COATING`                              VARCHAR(50),
    `EXTERIOR_INSUL`                                VARCHAR(50),
    `MANUFACTURER`                                  VARCHAR(50),
    `MANUFACTURE_DATE`                              DATE,
    `MANUFACTURE_NO`                                VARCHAR(50),
    `INTERNAL_ANODES`                               VARCHAR(50),
    `ASSOC_PSV`                                     VARCHAR(50),
    `MAINT_ITEM_CODE`                               VARCHAR(50),
    `SERV_TYPE`                                     VARCHAR(50),
    `EQUIP_CLASS`                                   VARCHAR(50),
    `EQUIP_SUBCLASS`                                VARCHAR(50),
    `PROCESS_UNIT`                                  VARCHAR(50),
    `RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INTERVAL`             DOUBLE,
    `LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL`                 DATE,
    `NEXT_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL`                 DATE,
    `RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INTERVAL`             DOUBLE,
    `LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL`                 DATE,
    `NEXT_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL`                 DATE,
    `DESIGN_LIFE`                                   DOUBLE,

    /*PRIMARY AND FOREIGN KEY DEFINITIONS*/
    PRIMARY KEY (EQUIPMENT_ID),

    /*INDEX FIELDS TO INCREASE PERFORMANCE REDUCES NUMBER OF ACCESSES (N) FROM N to LOG2(N) I.E. AN EXPONENTIAL DECREASE
     *APPLYING THESE INDEXES TO PRIMARY KEY FIELDS ALSO REMOVES THE REQUIREMENT FOR THE SYSTEM TO SEARCH FOR DUPLICATES
     *INDEXES ONLY INCREASE THE DISK SPACE REQUIRED OF THE DATABASE.
     *ALL DATABASE SEARCHING SHOULD ALWAYS BE DONE ON THE PRIMARY KEY INDEXED FIELD.
     */
    INDEX EQUIPMENT_INDEX (EQUIPMENT_ID)

) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IDMAS_VESSELS.DAMAGE_MECHANISM
(   /*FIELD NAME*/                                              /*DATA TYPE AND RESTRICTIONS*/
    `DAMAGE_MECHANISM_ID`                                       VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `EQUIPMENT_ID`                                              VARCHAR(20),
    `DESCRIPTION`                                               VARCHAR(50),
    `REMEDIATION_STATUS`                                        VARCHAR(10),
    `DAMAGE_MECHANISM_TYPE`                                     enum('QUALITATIVE', 'QUANTITATIVE') default NULL,
    `INSPECTION_STRATEGY`                                       VARCHAR(20),
    `AGE_RELATED`                                               enum('YES', 'NO') NOT NULL default 'NO',
    `FEASIBLE`                                                  enum('YES', 'NO') NOT NULL default 'NO',
    `NOTES_ON_FEASIBILITY`                                      TEXT,
    `MIN_REMAINING_LIFE`                                        DOUBLE,
    `MAX_ACR`                                                   DOUBLE,
    `MINIMUM_CALCULATED_RBI_INTERVAL`                           DOUBLE,
    `MAXIMUM_CRITICALITY_RATING`                                VARCHAR(20),
    `RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL`              DOUBLE,
    `LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL`                             DATE,
    `NEXT_INSPECTION_DATE_INTERNAL`                             DATE,
    `NOTES_ON_RECOMMENDED_RBI_INTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL`     TEXT,
    `RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL`              DOUBLE,
    `LAST_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL`                             DATE,
    `NEXT_INSPECTION_DATE_EXTERNAL`                             DATE,
    `NOTES_ON_RECOMMENDED_RBI_EXTERNAL_INSPECTION_INTERVAL`     TEXT,

    /*PRIMARY AND FOREIGN KEY DEFINITIONS*/
    PRIMARY KEY (DAMAGE_MECHANISM_ID, EQUIPMENT_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (EQUIPMENT_ID) REFERENCES EQUIPMENT(EQUIPMENT_ID),

    /*ADD TABLE INDEXES TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE*/
    INDEX DAMAGE_MECHANISM_INDEX (EQUIPMENT_ID, DAMAGE_MECHANISM_ID)

) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IDMAS_VESSELS.CML
(   /*FIELD NAME*/                                  /*DATA TYPE AND RESTRICTIONS*/
    `CML_ID`                                        INT NOT NULL,
    `CML_LOCATION`                                  VARCHAR(20),
    `STATUS`                                        enum('C','X','A','U') NOT NULL default 'C',
    `REMEDIATION_STATUS`                            VARCHAR(1),
    `EQUIPMENT_ID`                                  VARCHAR(20),
    `DAMAGE_MECHANISM_ID`                           VARCHAR(50),
    `CML_TYPE`                                      VARCHAR(50),
    `LAST_INSPECTION_DATE`                          DATE,
    `NOMINAL_DIAMETER_MM`                           DOUBLE,
    `OUTSIDE_DIAMETER_MM`                           DOUBLE,
    `MEAN_DIAMETER_MM`                              DOUBLE,
    `NOMINAL_WALL_THICKNESS_MM`                     DOUBLE,
    `MINIMUM_REMAINING_WALL_THICKNESS_MM`           DOUBLE,
    `DEPTH_OF_LOSS_FROM_NWT_MM`                     DOUBLE,
    `THICKNESS_WALL_LOSS_PERCENTAGE`                DOUBLE,
    `PHOTO`                                         INT,
    `MINIMUM_ALLOWABLE_WALL_THICKNESS_MM`           DOUBLE,
    `ACTUAL_CORROSION_RATE_MM_PER_YEAR`             DOUBLE,
    `MAX_CALCULATED_CORROSION_RATE`                 DOUBLE,
    `DAMAGE_LOOP_MAXIMUM_CORROSION_RATE`            DOUBLE,
    `APPLIED_CORROSION_RATE`                        DOUBLE,
    `APPLIED_CORROSION_RATE_NOTES_AND_ENTERED_BY`   TEXT,
    `FAILURE_MODE`                                  VARCHAR(50),
    `REMAINING_LIFE_BASED_ON_ACR`                   DOUBLE,
    `END_OF_LIFE`                                   DATE,
    `LR_LD_APPLIED`                                 DOUBLE,
    `POF_APPLIED`                                   INT(1),
    `DAMAGE_MECHANISM_VISUAL`                       TEXT,
    `FAILURE_MODE_VISUAL`                           TEXT,
    `POF_APPLIED_VISUAL`                            INT(1),
    `POF_APPLIED_VISUAL_COMMENT`                    TEXT,
    `CRITICALITY_RATING_VISUAL`                     INT(2),
    `CRITICALITY_RATING_APPLIED`                    VARCHAR(10),
    `DEGRADATION_MECHANISM`                         DOUBLE,
    `RELIABLE_MONITORING`                           DOUBLE,
    `MULTIPLE_INSPECTIONS`                          DOUBLE,
    `CONFIDENCE_SCORE`                              DOUBLE,
    `CONFIDENCE_RATING`                             VARCHAR(50),
    `INSPECTION_INTERVAL_FACTOR_APPLIED`            DOUBLE,
    `RISK_BASED_INSPECTION_INTERVAL_APPLIED_YEARS`  DOUBLE,
    `RECOMMENDED_REMEDIATION`                       TEXT,

    /*PRIMARY AND FOREIGN KEY DEFINITIONS*/
    PRIMARY KEY (EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (EQUIPMENT_ID, DAMAGE_MECHANISM_ID) REFERENCES DAMAGE_MECHANISM(EQUIPMENT_ID, DAMAGE_MECHANISM_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (CML_TYPE) REFERENCES CML_TYPES(CML_TYPE),
    FOREIGN KEY (REMEDIATION_STATUS) REFERENCES REMEDIATION_STATUSES(REMEDIATION_STATUS),

    /*ADD TABLE INDEXES TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE*/
    INDEX CML_INDEX (EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID)

) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IDMAS_VESSELS.INSPECTION
(   /*FIELD NAME*/                                  /*DATA TYPE AND RESTRICTIONS*/
    `INSPECTION_NO`                                 INT NOT NULL,
    `STATUS`                                        enum('P','A','S','R') NOT NULL default 'P',
    `CML_ID`                                        INT NOT NULL,
    `EQUIPMENT_ID`                                  VARCHAR(20),
    `INSPECTION_TYPE`                               VARCHAR(50),
    `SCOPE_COMMENTS`                                TEXT,
    `NOMINAL_WALL_THICKNESS`                        DOUBLE,
    `MINIMUM_REMAINING_WALL_THICKNESS`              DOUBLE,
    `WALL_LOSS`                                     DOUBLE,
    `SERVICE_YEARS`                                 DOUBLE,
    `CORROSION_RATE_ACTUAL_SHORT_TERM_MM_PER_YEAR`  DOUBLE,
    `CONDITION`                                     VARCHAR(50),
    `INSPECTION_DATE`                               DATE,
    `NDT_REPORT_NUMBER`                             VARCHAR(20),
    `INSPECTION_COMMENTS`                           TEXT,
    `INSPECTION_SCOPE`                              TEXT,
    `WORK_ORDER`                                    TEXT,
    `INPECTOR_NAME`                                 VARCHAR(50),
    `INPECTION_COMPANY`                             VARCHAR(50),
    `PHOTO`                                         INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    /*PRIMARY AND FOREIGN KEY DEFINITIONS*/
    PRIMARY KEY (EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID, INSPECTION_NO),
    FOREIGN KEY (EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID) REFERENCES CML(EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID),

    /*ADD TABLE INDEXES TO IMPROVE PERFORMANCE*/
    /*INDEX ON PHOTO FIELD REQUIRED TO ALLOW AUTO INCREMENTING OF FIELD*/
    INDEX INSPECTION_INDEX (EQUIPMENT_ID, CML_ID, INSPECTION_NO),
    INDEX `PHOTO` (`PHOTO`)
    -- INDEX INSPECTION_DATE (INSPECTION_DATE)

) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: I would start by creating a table with all those complex values waiting to store into `c`.  Then I would spend a lot of time proofreading the table.  If this monster update screws up, you will have a mess.  And you may not know that it is a mess.

Comment: A `PRIMARY KEY` is an `INDEX`; don't add redundant indexes (such as CML_TYPE).

Comment: `INT(1)` -- the `(1)` means nothing.  Perhaps you want `TINYINT`?

Comment: Don't use `(m,n)` on `DOUBLE`; either toss it or use `DECIMAL(m,n)`.

Comment: `DOUBLE` is probably overkill (8 bytes, ~16 significant digits); consider `FLOAT` (4 bytes; ~7 significant digits).

Comment: @Rick thanks for the feedback. Just one question. When you say creating a table with all those complex values, will this improve the speed of the update? Good call on the index mistake. I have corrected this in my source code. And I will review all my datatypes as suggested :)

Comment: It _might_ help the speed.  Especially if multiple connections are touching the table simultaneously.